# Linux distribution that still ships with KDE3?

Tags: linux, kde, distribution-choice

Is there any Linux distribution that still comes with support of KDE3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also there is [trinity desktop](http://www.trinitydesktop.org/), that is based on kde 3.5. You can install it on Debian Lenny, Debian Squeeze, Ubuntu Karmic to Oneiric, RHEL 5-6, Fedora 15 and Slackware 12.2-13.1.

Comment: I'll look into TDE , seems good

Comment: Trinity is not shipped with Dedian and/or Ubuntu, Slackware, Fedora. I suggest openSUSE if youy want official support.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenSUSE 12.1:](http://en.opensuse.org/KDE3)

> As of openSUSE 12.1 KDE 3 desktop is included as officially supported part of the distribution. Additional KDE 3 software can be installed from community-supported KDE:KDE3 repository.

(KDE3, not Trinity)

Answer (score 1):

KDE3 is shipped with openSUSE.
LiveDVD:
http://susestudio.com/download/2dd3fc0c6ad40f78c4a53b0e4fdd7a8b/OpenSUSE_12.1_KDE3.x86_64-1.0.7.iso

Other distributions that include KDE3 are AltLinux (see, e.g., the [kdebase](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/Sisyphus/srpms/kdebase) package), aLinux and Pardus Corporate.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [CentOS 5.7](http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=centos) still uses kde 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Gentoo has a portage overlay for KDE-3.5: http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/desktop/kde/